# Folders last modified time stamps are not updated in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

After changing any .cpp file in Visual Studio, the last modified time stamp for the file's folder is not updated. What's happening ?

Comment: Some applications have to be closed before the time stamp is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7, Server 2008, and 2008R2 only update the modified on a folder if the folder properties have been changed (i.e. location, permission, name).

Comment: That's not correct. If I make any change to a Word (.docx) document, the folder containing that doc will have its modified stamp updated.